# How to get the type of the elements in a declared TList

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe3, rtti

I'd like to know if there is a way to get the type of the elements of a declared, but not instantiated, TList. I can capture the class of an object property like this:

```
MyList: TList<TMyObject> read FMyList;

MyRTTIProperty: TRttiProperty;    
NewObject: TObject;
PropertyClass: TClass;

MyRttiProperty := MyRttiType.GetProperty('MyList');
PropertyClass := MyRTTIProperty.PropertyType.Handle.TypeData.ClassType; // (returns TList<TMyObject>)
NewObject := PropertyClass.Create;
```

This way I can instantiate my list correctly. But now I also want to get the class of the elements, TMyObject, so that I can instantiate them, fill its properties and add to the list. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, RTTI is not flexible enough to give you information about Generic parameters.  You will likely have to manually parse the value of `MyRTTIProperty.PropertyType.Name` (`TList<TMyObject>`) to extract the Generic type name (`TMyObject`), then use `TRttiContext.FindType()` to get the RTTI for that type, and then finally you can create instances of its `ClassType` as needed.