# Get TList type from propInfo

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Calls the following code in the `typInfo` module:

```
propInfo.propType^.name
```

For properties of type `TList<TMyClass>` returns the result: `TList <main.TMyClass>` . Is it possible to get a `TMyClass` separately (without working with the result as with a string)?

Comment: Is this basically your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/24183823/8216190

Comment: @null, yes, thanks.